# Adding OData V3 controller at runtime - can't find controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have an OData V3 C# project under VS2013 where I want to load/inject an ODataController in a separate class library at runtime and have that service a route.  The problem is that I cannot get the route to resolve to a controller. e.g. http://localhost/odata/Tests

```
"No type was found that matches the controller named 'TestsController'"
```

Here's what my controller looks like in the separate class library:

```
namespace WebApi.Extensions
{
  public class TestsController : ODataController
  {
    var t = "some string";

    public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Test> queryOptions)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

And in my WebApi Register() method I have this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
  var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

  <lots of 'local' builder.EntitySet<***>("***") calls>

  builder.EntitySet<Test>("Tests");

  var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("<full path to classlib.dll>");
  // test that we can find and load an instance
  var type = assembly.GetType("WebApi.Extensions.TestsController");
  var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  // no errors so far.  I can 'see' into 'obj'

  config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel() );

}
```

Can anyone see why I cannot get the route to resolve to the controller class?  Am I missing something that hooks it together?

Answer (score 0):

I found what i was missing.

[Customizing controller discovery in ASP.Net](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/)

You essentially write your own and register a custom DefaultAssembliesResolver where you take the list of assemblies that are automatically lifted from the bin directory (if hosting under IIS), and add your own assemblies from whatever directory you want.

Note: the posted source code in the link above has a bug in it.  Look through the blog comments.